# Why doesn't debugging work when using Guava libraries in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, guava

When I debug and the marker goes to the point to use Guava, the whole debugging session crashes. It says that no source attachment was found for Guava.
How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to download source jar and add to your build path

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse 4.3.1 (probably in the older versions too):

1. get the Guava source code (a source jar is available at [Maven](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/15.0/guava-15.0-sources.jar))
2. in the Eclipse project explorer pane, look for the Guava jar
3. right click on the jar file, select *Properties*
4. go to the *Java Source Attachment* tab
5. put the source jar from step 1 in the *External location* field

That should allow Eclipse to find the source.